# G-d traveling 18,000 worlds

Tags: midrash, masecheth-avodah-zarah

What’s the deeper meaning behind this midrash in Avodah Zara 3b:

> ובליליא מאי עביד איבעית אימא מעין יממא ואיבעית אימא רוכב על כרוב קל
> שלו ושט בשמונה עשר אלף עולמות שנאמר (תהלים סח, יח) רכב אלהים רבותים
> אלפי שנאן אל תקרי שנאן אלא שאינן
>
> And what does He do by night? — If you like you may say, the kind of
> thing He does by day; or it may be said that He rides a light cherub,
> and floats in eighteen thousand worlds; for it is said, The chariots
> of God are myriads, even thousands shinan.  Do not read Shinan,
> [repeated], but she-enan [that are not]

It says that in His free time, Gd flies around 18,000 worlds? What are these worlds, why the number 18k, etc.

Comment: Deep subject! אמנם רז"ל פירשו בכמה מקומות מציאות עולמות שונים אשר הם ברורים וניכרים ועיני המבינים ולא לעיני בשר של הכסילים. והפליגו במספרם בכמה מקומות כמו מה שאיתא (ויק"ר פרשה י"ח ועי' שבת קנ"ב) על פסוק כי הולך אדם לבית עולמו **כל צדיק יש לו עולם בפני עצמו**. ויותר מופלגתן בשילהי עוקצין ובפרק חלק דעתיד להנחיל לכל צדיק וצדיק ש"י עולמות שנאמר להנחיל אוהבי יש. (Sichat Malachei HaSharet)

Comment: Interesting. The source that Rabbi Kaii quoted seems to align with the idea of 18.000 tzadikkim [Sukkah 45b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.45b.5?ven=Daf_Shevui&lang=bi)

Comment: Hmmm both great inputs. I wonder how it all connects. Surely you can interpret the 18k worlds as tzaddikim (and in line with the saying from Pirkei Avot that a person is like a world), but I wonder the significance of that number and how the 310 worlds relate to it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [Yechezkel 48:35](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.48.35?lang=bi), the prophet says:

> It shall be round about eighteen thousand measures: and the name of the city from that day shall be, The L-rd is there.

The Tosafos Yom Tov [(Tzuras Habayis, 80:4)](https://www.sefaria.org/The_Third_Beit_HaMikdash.80.4?vhe=Tzurat_Beit_HaMikdash,_by_Rabbi_Yom_Tov_Lippman_Heller,_Moznaim_Pub_Corp._2016&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) says that the eighteen thosuand measures are a reference to the 18.000 worlds that are under the protection of G-d.

See also the Gemara in [Sukkah 45b](https://www.sefaria.org/Sukkah.45b.5?ven=Daf_Shevui&lang=bi):

> Did not Rava say, There is a row of 18,000 righteous men before the Holy One, blessed be He, for it is said, “It shall be eighteen thousand round about [and the name of the city from that day on shall be ‘The Lord Is There'” (Ezekiel 48:35)? This is no difficulty:  The former number refers to those who see Him through a bright speculum, the latter to those who do not see him through a bright speculum.

> Explanation is seemingly required regarding the following point: Scripture specifies the city’s dimensions on all four sides, and also mentions the sum of its perimeter. We do not find this type of redundancy for the other measurements mentioned in the narrative. Similarly, there is no such redundancy for the dimensions of the Great Terumah, nor for any of its sections, nor for the Temple Mount, nor for any other areas of the Beis HaMikdash. To offer a resolution: The text is informing the inhabitants of the exile that the city’s perimeter will be 18,000 measuring rods, which is equivalent to the number of worlds through which the Holy One, blessed be He, glides at night. As stated in Tractate Avodah Zarah: “What does He do by night?... It may be said that He rides a light cherub, and glides in 18,000 worlds, as intimated by the verse, ‘The chariot of God is twice (שִׁנְאָן) 10,000 times 2,000 angels.’ Do not read shin’an, ‘twice,’ [rather] read [it] she’einan, ‘that are not’ [i.e., twice 10,000 minus 2,000].” Thus, by mentioning the dimension 18,000, the verse is alluding to these worlds.

In the Milstein-edition [(Artscroll, p. 427)](https://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422616192.html) [1](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.48.35?lang=bi) it quotes the Maharal's Chiddushei Aggadah and says that these (eighteen thousand worlds) are the total number of worlds that are under the protecion of G-d. So it seems that it is taken literally.

The Gemara in [Sanhedrin (97b)](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.97b.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) refers to tzadikkim -righteous people - when mentioning 18.000:

> Apropos that verse, Abaye said: The world has no fewer than thirty-six righteous people in each generation who greet the Divine Presence, as it is stated: “Happy are all they who wait for Him [lo]” (Isaiah 30:18). The numerical value of lo, spelled lamed vav, is thirty-six. The Gemara asks: Is that so? But doesn’t Rava say: The row of the righteous before the Holy One, Blessed be He, extends eighteen thousand parasangs, as it is stated with regard to the city of God at the end of days: “It shall be eighteen thousand reeds round about, and the name of the city from that day shall be: The Lord is there” (Ezekiel 48:35)? The Gemara answers: It is not difficult; this statement of Abaye refers to the thirty-six righteous people who view the Divine Presence through a luminous crystal [be’ispaklarya], and that statement of Rava refers to the multitudes who view the Divine Presence through a crystal that is not luminous.

The Iyun Yaakov (עיון יעקב) builds upon this statement and quotes the Torah in [Mishlei 10:25](https://www.sefaria.org/Proverbs.10.25?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), where it says that the righteous people are the foundation of the world, tzadik yesod olam.

> but the righteous is an everlasting foundation.

> The Gemara here refers to these Tzadikim by calling them "worlds," because the Tzadik is the foundation of the world, which enables the world to endure, as the verse says, "Tzadik Yesod Olam" (Mishlei 10:25). [...] The Gemara is teaching that Hash-m's bond with, and protection of, the Jewish people is maintained at night, when the people are sleeping and not involved in Mitzvos, because Hash-m remembers the 18,000 Tzadikim in His inner circle, who lived throughout the generations of the history of the Jewish people and who were "Kal ka'Nesher" to give up their lives for their love of Hashem. [(Rabbi Mordecai Kornfeld from  Kollel Iyun Hadaf of Yerushalayim)](https://dafyomi.co.il/azarah/insites/az-dt-003.htm)

---

[1](https://www.sefaria.org/Ezekiel.48.35?lang=bi) Rabbi Nosson Scherman, Rabbi Meir Zlotowitz

Comment: Interesting how Maharal interprets it literally because he usually takes the metaphorical route. Great answer!

Comment: If it is to be taken literally, like according to the Maharal, then what are these worlds? Different planets with life forms? Alternate dimensions? Curious to hear more about this.

Comment: @Seeker you should ask this in a new question. Great question though